# Order information are not displaying in the admin Panel of magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, admin-panel

[image]

I am not seeing any order on my order menu. It is showing a blank white screen. Please tell me a suitable solution to resolve this error. 
Thank You

Comment: Hi Manish, please put your site in developer mode and then check your log files to get more details about the issue. Also look for any errors in your browser console.

Comment: i am not able to understand the error in log file. there are many errors in the log file, not able to find out error for order details.

Comment: The latest error will come at last.

Comment: 2017-12-12T05:50:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): 
2017-12-12T05:50:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): 
2017-12-12T05:54:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): 
2017-12-12T05:54:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): 
2017-12-12T05:55:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons  in /home/jodhpurd/public_html/cron.php on line 66
2017-12-12T05:55:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons  in /home/jodhpurd/public_html/cron.php on line 67
2017-12-12T05:55:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): 
2017-12-12T05:55:50+00:00 DEBUG (7):